# Extra vertical space in header when using scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I am trying to create a custom header including an image with a certain height. In an recent project, I have used the `fancyhdr` which worked pretty well. However, as the usage of `fancyhdr` together with KOMA classes is discouraged I would like to switch to `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Basically, it works but extra vertical space is added below the image. This looks strange and yields an overfull vbox warning. The following MWE demonstrates this behaviour:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
%
\newlength{\theLogoHeight}
\setlength{\theLogoHeight}{10mm}
%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\newgeometry{top=3\theLogoHeight,
  headheight=\theLogoHeight,
  headsep=\theLogoHeight,
  footskip=\theLogoHeight,
  bottom=2\theLogoHeight,
  inner=2\theLogoHeight,
  outer=2\theLogoHeight
}
%
\RequirePackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{%
  \chead{%
    \rule{0.1cm}{\theLogoHeight}%
  }%
}
%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text
\end{document}
```

What is the reason for this extra vertical space? And how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202730/158962 However, it does not use the `geometry` package.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257357/158962 This seems to be the pretty same question, but I can't figure out how the solution there should work. I have tried it without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`headheight` is the total height of the page header, i.e. the height plus the depth of the header. Your logo is put on the baseline with the height `\theLogoHeight`. So the height of the header must be at least `\theLogoHeight`, but there is also the depth of the header which depends on the font size.

Example to visualize the size of header depth:

```latex
\chead{%
  \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{0.1cm}{\dp\strutbox}% to visualize the depth of the header
  Example%
  \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{0.1cm}{\dp\strutbox}% to visualize the depth of the header
  \rule{0.1cm}{\theLogoHeight}%
}
```

[image]

You can enlarge `headheight` and reduce `headsep` or you can raise down the logo by `\dp\strutbox`:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
%
\newlength{\LogoHeight}
\setlength{\LogoHeight}{10mm}
%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\newgeometry{top=3\LogoHeight,
  headheight=\LogoHeight,
  headsep=\LogoHeight,
  footskip=\LogoHeight,
  bottom=2\LogoHeight,
  inner=2\LogoHeight,
  outer=2\LogoHeight
}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\newpairofpagestyles{firstpage}{%
  \chead{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\rule{0.1cm}{\LogoHeight}}}% <- raise down the logo
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text Test Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

The remaining space between the logo and the text body is defined by the value of `headsep` in your geometry options. You can reduce this value or remove the option to get a smaller sep between page header and text body.

Comment: Thanks  a lot, it works like a charm now! Tricky follow-up problem though, as I want to position three lines of text next to the logo. But I'll play around first...

Comment: I ended up just adding some extra space to `headheight` -- then both text (in a vbox) and image fitted in nicely without any warning. The extra space is calculated with 0.3\baselineskip or \dp\strutbox, which should yield the same, right?